# Ubuntu: How can I disable boot and logout screen

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I want to be able to see all stuff from the boot process, just like in Debian.

I instaled `startupmanager` but It only change boot screen to more ugly.

I search google and find that you must remove "quiet" from /boot/grub/menu.lst but I don't have that file on my system.

Comment: Do you know if you are using the old grub or the new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are using *[Grub 2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2)*. I haven't tried it, but acording to this **[article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)**.  You will need to change `/etc/default/grub`, so that the line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

becomes:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

in other words, remove `quiet` and `splash` from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable.

**update:** from [jcubic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1806/jcubic)'s comment:

also remove `splash` and  `vga=769` from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable.

Comment: I also had to remove `"splash vga=769"` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` varible.